# Does the App.js file re-render if we are using context API from a separate file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

If I am managing the states of all variables in a separate (default) context file other than App.js, will the App.js file re-render whenever the variables inside of it change?

For example: In the bottom file, if the value of the "isLoggedIn" variable changes from false to true, and this change is triggered when a button is clicked in the "" component, will the App.js component be re-rendered?
Because, in my App.js file, if the value of "isLoggedIn" changes to "true", it should render different components namely "Signup", "Newpost", and "Postlist".

```
import "./App.css";
import { useContext } from "react";
import LoginPage from "./Login/LoginPage";
import NewPost from "./Posts/NewPost";
import PostList from "./Posts/PostList";
import Signup from "./Signup/Signup";
import AuthContext from "./store/auth-context";
import { AuthContextProvider } from "./store/auth-context";

const expenses = [
  {
    name: "Lakshay Gupta",
    content:
      " Amet minim mollit non deserunt ullamco est sit aliqua dolor do amet sint. Velit officia consequat duis enim velit mollit. Exercitation veniam consequat sunt nostrud amet.",
    posted: "5mins ago",
    comments: "16 comments",
  },
  {
    name: "Naman Sukhija",
    content:
      " Amet minim mollit non deserunt ullamco est sit aliqua dolor do amet sint. Velit officia consequat duis enim velit mollit. Exercitation veniam consequat sunt nostrud amet.",
    posted: "1hour ago",
    comments: "24 comments",
  },
  {
    name: "William Harris",
    content:
      " Amet minim mollit non deserunt ullamco est sit aliqua dolor do amet sint. Velit officia consequat duis enim velit mollit. Exercitation veniam consequat sunt nostrud amet.",
    posted: "3mins ago",
    comments: "29 comments",
  },
];

function App() {
  const ctx = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <AuthContextProvider>
      {!ctx.isLoggedIn && <LoginPage></LoginPage>}
      {console.log(ctx.isLoggedIn)}

      {ctx.isLoggedIn && (
        <div className="posts-area">
          {ctx.registerIsShown && <Signup></Signup>}
          <NewPost></NewPost>
          <PostList items={expenses}></PostList>{" "}
        </div>
      )}
    </AuthContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Context file

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  registerIsShown: false,
  onLogin: (email,pass) => {}, 
  onShow: () => {} ,
  onHide: () => {}
});

export const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLogin] = useState(false);

  const submitLoginHandler = (event) => {
    
    setLogin(!isLoggedIn);
  };

  const [registerIsShown, setRegisterIsShown] = useState(false);

  const showRegisterHandler = () => {
    setRegisterIsShown(true);
  };

  const hideRegisterHandler = () => {
    setRegisterIsShown(false);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
        registerIsShown: registerIsShown,
        onLogin: submitLoginHandler,
        onShow: showRegisterHandler,
        onHide:  hideRegisterHandler
      }}
    >{props.children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
export default AuthContext;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it should not rerender (although you can check this yourself by doing a `console.log("rerender")` before the `return` in `App.js`.

The problem here is that you can't use `const ctx = useContext(AuthContext);` outside of the `AuthContextProvider` (or you can, but it will always be the default context:)

```
{
  isLoggedIn: false,
  registerIsShown: false,
  onLogin: (email,pass) => {}, 
  onShow: () => {} ,
  onHide: () => {}
}
```

In order to use the context correctly, make a new component that uses the context:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <MyNewComponent />
    </AuthContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

// MyNewComponent.jsx

const expenses = [
  {
    name: "Lakshay Gupta",
    content:
      " Amet minim mollit non deserunt ullamco est sit aliqua dolor do amet sint. Velit officia consequat duis enim velit mollit. Exercitation veniam consequat sunt nostrud amet.",
    posted: "5mins ago",
    comments: "16 comments",
  },
  {
    name: "Naman Sukhija",
    content:
      " Amet minim mollit non deserunt ullamco est sit aliqua dolor do amet sint. Velit officia consequat duis enim velit mollit. Exercitation veniam consequat sunt nostrud amet.",
    posted: "1hour ago",
    comments: "24 comments",
  },
  {
    name: "William Harris",
    content:
      " Amet minim mollit non deserunt ullamco est sit aliqua dolor do amet sint. Velit officia consequat duis enim velit mollit. Exercitation veniam consequat sunt nostrud amet.",
    posted: "3mins ago",
    comments: "29 comments",
  },
];

const MyNewComponent = ()=>{
  const ctx = useContext(AuthContext);

  if(!ctx.isLoggedIn){
    return (<LoginPage></LoginPage>)
  }
  return (    
        <div className="posts-area">
          {ctx.registerIsShown && <Signup></Signup>}
          <NewPost></NewPost>
          <PostList items={expenses}></PostList>{" "}
        </div>
  )
}

export default MyNewComponent;
```